# Find if some words in array value are in same array php

Tags: php, array

I have to find where a given string is in my multidimensional array.
So this is my array

```
$input = array(array('time' => '18:31:00', 'artist' => 'LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW'), array('time' => '18:32:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:33:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:34:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:35:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN'));
```

I have to find at what time I can find this

```
$artista_inserito = 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN';
```

So I use a function to delimiter my array and even string

```
function multiexplode($delimiters, $string)
{

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

// array with string delimeter
$array_delimiter_artisti = array(' FEAT ', ' feat ', ' FT ', ' ft ', ' + ', ' AND ', ' and ', ' E ', ' e ', ' VS ', ' vs ', ' FEAT. ', ' feat. ', ' FT. ', ' ft. ', ' VS. ', ' vs. ', ' , ', ' & ');

// I split the current artist
$artisti_inseriti = multiexplode($array_delimiter_artisti, $artista_inserito);
```

So I search the given string un my array

```
foreach ($input as $split) {
    $time = $split['time'];
    $artist = $split['artist'];
    $lista_artisti = multiexplode($array_delimiter_artisti, $artist);

    foreach ($lista_artisti as $nuovo) {
        $artista_split = $nuovo;

        // copy all new data in new array
        $nuovo_array_dati[] = array('time' => $time, 'artist' => $artista_split);
    }
}

foreach ($nuovo_array_dati as $controllo) {
    $time = $controllo['time'];
    $artist = $controllo['artist'];

    foreach ($artisti_inseriti as $trova_artista) {
        $artista_singolo = $trova_artista;



        foreach ($controllo as $index => $a) {
            if (strstr($a, $artista_singolo)) {
                // now I can print where I found the given string $artista_inserito
                echo "$artista_singolo  is at $time ";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my output

```
J BALVIN is at 18:32:00 
THE BLACK EYED PEAS is at 18:33:00 
J BALVIN is at 18:33:00 
THE BLACK EYED PEAS is at 18:34:00 
J BALVIN is at 18:34:00 
J BALVIN is at 18:35:00
```

Can I improve this?
Thanks

Comment: Merely splitting on whitespaces may not be a reliable way to search the haystacks with the generated needles.  I feel like this topic has been reviewed before.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/178870/141885  Also, according to the php documentation, it is not advised to use `strstr()` to check the existence of a substring in a string -- using `strpos()` is a better performer.  I don't see any reason to check the time column's data. Why do you only use the first element of `$array_delimiter_artisti`?

Comment: @mickmackusa Please don't use duplicates like this on Code Review. Our policy on duplicates [is a bit different from other Q&A sites](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3821/52915).

Comment: @mickmackusa I have to log at what time there is the same artist, so I have to check also the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bias *toward* regex because I'm generally comfortable with most techniques, so I'll recommend condensing your array of delimiters into a single regex pattern and employ `preg_split()` to execute the explosion.

After splitting the search string into its separate artists, I am flipping the values & keys to optimize the lookup for later use in the nested loop.

Then as you iterate the haystack of artist times, you can re-use the splitting pattern, then iterate each individual artist and store the desired data for qualifying rows.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bRaJl))

```
$fullArtistTimes = [
    ['time' => '18:31:00', 'artist' => 'LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW'],
    ['time' => '18:32:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN'],
    ['time' => '18:33:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'],
    ['time' => '18:34:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'],
    ['time' => '18:35:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN']
];

$fullArtist = 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN';

$artistDelimiters = '~ (?:[+e,&]|and|f(?:ea)?t\.?|vs\.?) ~i';

$artists = array_flip(preg_split($artistDelimiters, $fullArtist));

$result = [];
foreach ($fullArtistTimes as $row) {
    foreach (preg_split($artistDelimiters, $row['artist']) as $artist) {
        if (isset($artists[$artist])) {
            $result[] = "{$artist} is at {$row['time']}";
        }
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'J BALVIN is at 18:32:00',
  1 => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS is at 18:33:00',
  2 => 'J BALVIN is at 18:33:00',
  3 => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS is at 18:34:00',
  4 => 'J BALVIN is at 18:34:00',
  5 => 'J BALVIN is at 18:35:00',
)
```

If this does not work for all of your cases, then I would need to see more test cases and your desired result before I could properly adjust my snippet.

Comment: Thanks, my only problem is the $artistDelimiters, I have to retrieve the delimiters from a mysql table where the user can add or remove some words, so the delimiters has to be more simple

Comment: `'~ (?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($v){ return preg_quote($v, '~'); }, $databaseDelimiters)) . ') ~'`

Comment: If I use this I haven't same result
`code
 $databaseDelimiters = array(' FEAT ', ' feat ', ' FT ', ' ft ', ' + ', ' AND ', ' and ', ' E ', ' e ', ' VS ', ' vs ', ' FEAT. ', ' feat. ', ' FT. ', ' ft. ', ' VS. ', ' vs. ', ' , ', ' & ');

$artistDelimiters = '~ (?:' . implode('|', array_map(function ($v) {
    return preg_quote($v, '~');
}, $databaseDelimiters)) . ') ~';

$artists = array_flip(preg_split($artistDelimiters, $fullArtist));
`

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to delete the blank spaces... it is right? Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that bit.  Yes, `trim()` them (before even saving them to the db -- keep your data tidy).

Comment: Thanks! It's fully working